# Accelerate the optimizing process of Deep Learning Model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, bayesian-optimization

Bayesian Optimization is currently the best optimization method for deep learning model. Although it already offer a good optimizing time but I want to accelerate by

1. Instead of training every configurations for 100 epochs, I could use... say, 10 or 20 epochs.

   Instead of training on full training data, I could train using 30-40% of the training data.

Assuming that a good model will converge pretty fast after the first few epochs or little data. It could give us a insight of how well a model performs. After the optimizing process , the best model will be picked and train again on full epochs or full training data to increase the performance or generalization.

My question: will these hypothesis work?

Comment: Optimization method of neural networks is called gradient descent. Are you talking about hyper-parameter tuning? If yes, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41860817/712995), the answer discusses your 1 item. I'm not sure the 2 item is valid

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. Yes i am talking about hyper-parameter tuning. The discussion you sent me didn't discuss if reducing epoch size or training size a good strategy to accelerate the optimizing process

Comment: See the part about *learning curve prediction*. In short: yes, it can help

Comment: I read about it and find it very interesting , are you the author of the github link ? If so i do have some question on the implementation

Comment: Yes, but I think it's out of scope of cross-validated. Feel free to write an issue if you have questions

Comment: Can i contact you over email ? my is baothienpp@gmail.com

Comment: If there's something sensitive in your issue, it's of course can be handled privately. But I'd appreciate if you write it generally in the issue, as a start